# SQL Group By and Count on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a MySQL table with data as:-

```
country | city
---------------
italy   | milan
italy   | rome
italy   | rome
ireland | cork
uk      | london
ireland | cork
```

I want query this and group by the country and city and have counts of both the city and the country, like this:-

```
country | city   | city_count | country_count
---------------------------------------------
ireland | cork   |          2 |             2
italy   | milan  |          1 |             3
italy   | rome   |          2 |             3
uk      | london |          1 |             1
```

I can do:-

```
SELECT country, city, count(city) as city_count
FROM jobs
GROUP BY country, city
```

Which gives me:-

```
country | city   | city_count 
-----------------------------
ireland | cork   |          2 
italy   | milan  |          1 
italy   | rome   |          2
uk      | london |          1
```

Any pointer to getting the country_count too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT country, city, count(city) as city_count,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM jobs AS j2
        WHERE j1.country = j2.country) AS country_count
FROM jobs AS j1
GROUP BY country, city
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f99e86/1)

Comment: this is duplicated answer I am afraid

Comment: @dcieslak Compared to which answer posted prior to mine?

Comment: whatever, it's too simple ;) i can call you master of this query

Comment: this is extremely slow

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it in subquery on results.

```
  SELECT jm.country, jm.city, 
       count(city) as city_count,
       (select count(*) from jobs j where j.country = jm.country) as country_count
    FROM jobs jm
    GROUP BY jm.country, jm.city
```

[SQL Fidlle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7def/6/0)

Comment: This is a duplicate answer I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Use Self Join Instead.

```
select a.country,a.city,b.city_count,c.country_count
from jobs a
inner join (select count(1) as city_count, city
    from jobs
    group by city
) b on a.city = b.city
inner join (select count(1) as country_count, country 
    from jobs
    group by country
) c on a.country = c.country
group by country,city
```

Comment: this results in error

Comment: `Query Error: error: column reference "country" is ambiguous`

Answer (score 0):

i have written answer at that time Giorgos Betsos posted answer the same as my code so i have written in CTE also

we can achieve result in lot ways but here is the 2 solutions and second query is less complicated

```
declare @Table1 TABLE 
    ([country] varchar(7), [city] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ([country], [city])
VALUES
    ('italy', 'milan'),
    ('italy', 'rome'),
    ('italy', 'rome'),
    ('ireland', 'cork'),
    ('uk', 'london'),
    ('ireland', 'cork')
;
```

**First way**

```
   ;with CTE AS (
    select T.country,T.city,count(T.city)TCity from @Table1 T
    group by country,city )
    select C.country,C.city,C.TCity,T.T from CTE C INNER JOIN (select count(country)T,country from @Table1 group by country )T
    ON T.country = C.country
    GROUP BY c.country,c.city,c.TCity,t.t
```

**Second way**

```
SELECT country, city, count(city) as citycnt,
           (SELECT count(*)
            FROM @Table1 AS TT
            WHERE T.country = TT.country) AS countrycnt
    FROM @Table1 AS T
    GROUP BY country, city
```